# Puppeteer: Chrome Remote Launch

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer

Is there a way to launch chrome in non headless mode from a docker container?

I have a node application inside a docker container and a headless chrome container where i can connect to. All works fine so far. To demonstrate what puppeteer is doing i want to launch a chrome in non headless mode on the host system. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start Chromium manually on your host machine and then connect to its WebSocket port using `puppeteer.connect()` - https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.8.0&show=api-puppeteerconnectoptions . Don't forgot to open the WS port to container.

We also experimented with running Puppeteer in non-headless mode inside the Docker container using XVFB (X virtual framebuffer) and noVNC (https://github.com/novnc/noVNC) to display whats on the screen at HTML page served from the container. But that's not ideal for debugging.

If you just want to see which pages are opened and their screenshots you could use live-view https://github.com/apifytech/apify-js#puppeteer-live-view we build exactly for this use case.

Comment: Ok, i got a connection to my manually started chromium on the host system and puppeteer works the same as it does with the chromium in the docker container. But how can i see what puppeteer does, for e.g. filling a form?! There is no option { headless: false } for puppeteer.connect(). I tried to set puppeteer.defaultArgs({ headless: false }) but with no success.

Comment: You can start Chromium on the host system in non-headless mode. So you will see its windows and all the Puppeteer activity.

https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. But without --headless flag i can't connect to chromium on the host machine.
http://localhost:9222/json/version ist not available over ip. I think i've to investigate that further.

Comment: I finally got it to work. The missing part was to open a ssh tunnel from my docker container to the host machine with:
ssh -4 -L 9222:localhost:9222 myHostUser@host

Comment: Broken link, should be https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.3.0&show=api-puppeteerconnectoptions